# How to .focus() on an element when it is visible with .fadetoggle() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the jquery code below in rails:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-new-team-button").on("click", function(){
        $(".new-team-form").fadeToggle("fast", function(){
            $(".new-team-form").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

On the click of a button inside a div on my webpage, it should show or hide a div containing a form(**.new-team-form**). However, when the div is visible/showing, I want the browser to put focus on the div because you have to scroll down quite a bit to see it. The fade-toggle is working completely fine. I just cant get it to focus on the form div. My theory on making the focus() action work resulted in the code above and I would be grateful for help on fixing it since it's clearly wrong.

Comment: Is the element an `input` ?

Comment: can you make fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried your code and it looks good


[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rudacujiwa/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use focus your div must have a `tabindex` attribute on it like:

```
<div class="new-team-form" tabindex="-1">Add data</div>
```

alternatively you can use [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method like:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('.new-team-form').offset().top);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wygs46r5/

Comment: BTW, -1 allows to focus on the element programmatically and you still cannot focus on it with such keys as TAB. Just a note.

Answer (score 0):

`.focus()` doesn't scroll, `.scrollTop(position)` does scroll. [JSFiddle with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kxhr865o/).
Edit: focus would scroll if called on an input field. scrollTop is a more generic solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first form element and focus on that. Using `.find(':input:visible').first().focus()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-new-team-button").on("click", function(){
        $(".new-team-form").fadeToggle("fast", function(){
            $(this).find(':input:visible').first().focus();
        });
    });
});
```